# property undefined when setting a property when calling a template

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to create a dynamic popup using bootstrap where from a html template of a modal, I dynamically add a header, body and footer. but when my code is executed, in the browser console I get some errors because from the beginning no values have been defined for header, body and footer.

I'm new and I'm not very used to object-oriented programming.

this is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-fh92s3?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

modal.service.ts

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {ModalModel} from './modal.model';
    import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

    declare let $: any;

    @Injectable()
    export class ModalService {

      modalData = new Subject<ModalModel>();

      modalDataEvent = this.modalData.asObservable();

      open(modalData: ModalModel) {

        this.modalData.next(modalData);

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
}
```

modal.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ModalService } from './modal.service';
    import {ModalModel} from './modal.model';

    declare let $: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-modal',
      templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './modal.component.css' ]
    })
    export class ModalComponent  {

      modalData: ModalModel;

      constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {
        this.modalService.modalDataEvent.subscribe((data) => {
          this.modalData = data;
        })
      }

 }
```

calling this service from any component

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ModalService } from '../modal/modal.service';
    import { ModalModel } from '../modal/modal.model';


    declare let $: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
    })
    export class HomeComponent  {

      modelData = new ModalModel();

      constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {

      }

      open() {
        this.modelData.header = 'This is my dynamic HEADER from Home component';
        this.modelData.body = 'This is my dynamic BODY from Home component';
        this.modelData.footer = 'This is my dynamic footer from Home component';
        this.modalService.open(this.modelData);
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Initialize your modalData with default value so that it can't throw error https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-a7csh6?file=app/modal/modal.component.ts Other ways is save navigation operator of `*ngIf` There are a lot of similar questions so i would close it

Comment: @yurzui thanks! but you just modified modal.component.ts? in my real code I avoid the error, but when I click on the button the values do not change.

Comment: why are you using jquery in angular project ?

Comment: yes....... why?

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'modalData' is only assigned when `subscribe` is called, but template binding happens before that (since the component is included from the start), when`modelData` is still undefined.

You can either initialise data like yurzui suggested, or also use the `?` operator, which will not evaluate the properties if the object is null or undefined.

```
  <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalData?.header}}</h4>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{modalData?.body}}</p>
  </div>
```

[Edited stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-asetsq?file=app/modal/modal.component.html)